# How to import a local .sql into a docker container with postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

Hi im trying to import my .sql with the creation of tables and inserts into a container database with postgres, something like this...

```
docker exec postgrescontainer psql -U postgres mydatabase < D:\"My documents"\desk\sql\database.sql
```

But when i see into the container, nothing happens and the relations of mydatabase are empty.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved adding -i in the flags

```
docker exec -i postgrescontaineer psql -U postgres mydatabase < D:\"My documents"\desk\sql\database.sql
```